# How do I read from a javascript object that appears empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

[image]
I have the following object array that looks empty when not opened. If I try console.log(object) then the object displays as below that I can click open, but as soon as I try console.log(object[0]) I get an undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

This is in a react.js app if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is likely because the logger is backfilling these values, and they actually aren't available at the time of `console.log`

Comment: Beyond the duplicate link above there is no way to help without seeing some code...in particlar the promise for the requested data and where you are trying to log it